# How can I avoid that Github rotates my jpg in my readme.md?

Tags: github, orientation, jpeg, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have added a image reference in my `readme.md` on github. The picture is a portrait format photo, but when I view it on the github page the picture is rotated.

I have tried clone the repo to a new location to confirm that the picture is indeed still portrait as expected in the repo.

The image part of the readme.md:

```
Here is a picture of the hardware setup. ![picture of the hardware setup](HelloButtonModule.jpg)
```

This is the [affected github repo](https://github.com/steenhulthin/HelloButtonModule/tree/c9545b250a4ba36e5ccc61603bf5840132db632e)

**Update**

Now I am really baffled I tried to simplify the problem in a [new repo](https://github.com/steenhulthin/githubreadmeimagerotation), but the picture shows up unrotated as (originally) expected.

**Update**

I have created a [repo with an exact copy of the picture](https://github.com/steenhulthin/githubreadmeimagerotation2). Then the picture is rotated.

Answer (score 17):

You could try simply opening the file and then re-saving it.  You may need to rotate 360 degrees before you save, however, this should work.

Comment: Crazily enough, this worked for me too.  Used ubuntu's default Image Viewer, opened the file and used Edit-->rotate clockwise 4 times.  committed this change, pushed to github, and the github readme image is now correctly rotated.  Odd but works!

Comment: GIMP seems to automatically notice the discrepancy and asks if you want to fix it. Just open, say yes, and export.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a Debian based distro, you can use `exiftran`.

```
sudo apt-get install exiftran
exiftran -ai *.jpg
```

This will automatically rotate all the .jpg files based on their exif data.

I ran

```
git clone https://github.com/steenhulthin/HelloButtonModule/
cd HelloButtonModule/
exif HelloButtonModule.jpg
```

and this produced:

```
EXIF tags in 'HelloButtonModule.jpg' ('Motorola' byte order):
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
Tag                 |Value
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
Image Width         |4128
Image Length        |2322
Manufacturer        |SAMSUNG
Model               |GT-I9505
Orientation         |Top-left
X-Resolution        |72
Y-Resolution        |72
Resolution Unit     |Inch
Software            |I9505XXUDMH8
Date and Time       |2013:10:16 23:22:57
YCbCr Positioning   |Centred
Image Width         |512
Image Length        |288
Compression         |JPEG compression
Orientation         |Right-top
X-Resolution        |72
Y-Resolution        |72
Resolution Unit     |Inch
Exposure Time       |1/33 sec.
F-Number            |f/2.2
Exposure Program    |Normal programme
ISO Speed Ratings   |100
Exif Version        |Exif Version 2.2
Date and Time (Origi|2013:10:16 23:22:57
Date and Time (Digit|2013:10:16 23:22:57
Components Configura|Y Cb Cr -
Shutter Speed       |5.06 EV (1/33 sec.)
Aperture            |2.28 EV (f/2.2)
Brightness          |2.44 EV (18.56 cd/m^2)
Exposure Bias       |0.00 EV
Maximum Aperture Val|2.28 EV (f/2.2)
Metering Mode       |Centre-weighted average
Light Source        |Unknown
Flash               |Flash did not fire
Focal Length        |4.2 mm
Maker Note          |98 bytes undefined data
User Comment        |METADATA-START
FlashPixVersion     |FlashPix Version 1.0
Colour Space        |sRGB
Pixel X Dimension   |4128
Pixel Y Dimension   |2322
Sensing Method      |One-chip colour area sensor
```

As you can see, the Orientation tag says top left. This means the EXIF data won't make a difference to the rotation, i.e. the image will appear the same on your computer and on Github.

I then ran

```
git clone https://github.com/steenhulthin/githubreadmeimagerotation2
cd githubreadmeimagerotation2/
exif HelloButtonModule.jpg
```

And I got:

```
EXIF tags in 'HelloButtonModule.jpg' ('Intel' byte order):
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
Tag                 |Value
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
Image Width         |4128
Image Length        |2322
Manufacturer        |SAMSUNG
Model               |GT-I9505
Orientation         |Right-top
X-Resolution        |72
Y-Resolution        |72
Resolution Unit     |Inch
Software            |I9505XXUDMH8
Date and Time       |2013:10:16 23:22:57
YCbCr Positioning   |Centred
Image Width         |512
Image Length        |288
Compression         |JPEG compression
Orientation         |Right-top
X-Resolution        |72
Y-Resolution        |72
Resolution Unit     |Inch
Exposure Time       |1/33 sec.
F-Number            |f/2.2
Exposure Program    |Normal programme
ISO Speed Ratings   |100
Exif Version        |Exif Version 2.2
Date and Time (Origi|2013:10:16 23:22:57
Date and Time (Digit|2013:10:16 23:22:57
Components Configura|Y Cb Cr -
Shutter Speed       |5.06 EV (1/33 sec.)
Aperture            |2.28 EV (f/2.2)
Brightness          |2.44 EV (18.56 cd/m^2)
Exposure Bias       |0.00 EV
Maximum Aperture Val|2.28 EV (f/2.2)
Metering Mode       |Centre-weighted average
Light Source        |Unknown
Flash               |Flash did not fire
Focal Length        |4.2 mm
Maker Note          |98 bytes undefined data
User Comment        |METADATA-START
FlashPixVersion     |FlashPix Version 1.0
Colour Space        |sRGB
Pixel X Dimension   |4128
Pixel Y Dimension   |2322
Sensing Method      |One-chip colour area sensor
```

Here the orientation says `Right-top` which means the right top corner of the image is currently in the top left corner. Github does not honor this information, so your image is displayed incorrectly.

I then ran `exiftran -ai HelloButtonModule.jpg` and this fixed the problem. There is a fork here https://github.com/texasflood/githubreadmeimagerotation2 which shows the correct rotation for the image.

If you are on Windows, IrfanView might work, courtesy of this question: https://superuser.com/questions/36645/how-to-rotate-images-automatically-based-on-exif-data

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the rotation as it is. Only the way it is shown on github.

Comment: Yes there is. I cloned your repos and checked. I think you've misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is caused by github's missing support for the EXIF "Orientation" tag.

Github shows the image data as they are contained in the JPEG file, which is the orientation in which they have been captured by the camera photo sensor. Additionally, the JPEG file includes an EXIF tag "Orientation" containing the value "right, top", which indicates that the image data are not to be interpreted as they are, but that the right side should actually be up. Apparently, github does not honor this tag.

The image in your second repository is not identical to the first one, but seems to have been edited to add the red arrow and text. My guess is that the editor interpreted the "Orientation" tag during loading, and then saved the image data in rotated form and with an "Orientation" tag value of "top, left".

For more information, see e.g. [JPEG Rotation and EXIF Orientation](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html).

Answer (score 2):

I still don't understand why this happens (@A.Donda's explanation sound plausible), but I found a solution.

I **resized the picture to 50% of the original** and [picture is no longer rotated](https://github.com/steenhulthin/HelloButtonModule/tree/ce8e86ed2f2a6558b0c775e759afce9a80490c4c#hardware-setup).

I would still be happy to know if there are alternatives to resizing though.